# Make Python List Unique in Functional way (map/reduce/filter)

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, functional-programming

Is there a way in Python of making a List unique through functional paradigm ?

Input : `[1,2,2,3,3,3,4]`

Output: `[1,2,3,4]` (In order preserving manner)

I know there are [other ways](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark) but none is in the functional way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to just delete adjacent occurrences try this:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y] if x==[] or x[-1] != y else x, your_list,[])
```

If you need to delete all but one ocurrence try this:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y] if not y in x else x, your_list,[])
```

Comment: Haha, +1 - I think we submitted that second option at exactly the same time :)

Comment: hahaha that's true. But I can't vote now, I have less than 15 points. Future +1 is coming :) ... Done

Comment: Ha, your points have almost doubled in 17 seconds! Yours is the better answer, so let's hope it is also your first accept :)

Comment: You should be able to simplify the logic a little by treating the initial element as the base case instead of an empty list: `reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y] if x[-1] != y else x, your_list[1:], your_list[0])`

Comment: what's reduce in Python 3?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
In [29]: a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4]

In [30]: reduce(lambda ac, v: ac + [v] if v not in ac else ac, a, [])
Out[30]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This uses a list accumulator (`ac`) and checks if the current value (`v`) is already in the list; if not, add the new element; if so, just return the list.

Also, this one is completely worthless/ugly/misguided and was more out of curiosity (and could be done much better, for sure):

```
In [11]: a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4]

In [12]: n = [None] * len(a)

In [13]: map(lambda b, c:(lambda i=n.__setitem__:(i(c,b)))() if b not in n else None, a, range(len(a)))
Out[13]: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

In [14]: filter(lambda x: x, n)
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have an ordered set, but you can cheat using `OrderedDict`. Well it's not purely functional, but does do in a pinch.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> x = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
>>> OrderedDict(zip(x, repeat(None))).keys()
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

> making a List unique through functional paradigm

Pretty straightforward: you need an entity that is a set-ish but also ordered with ordering the same as in initial list.

```
sorted(set(input), key=lambda element: input.index(element))
```

Bonus features: when initial array has duplicate elements, ordering is not guaranteed to exist (as in `[1,2,2,1]` case). Provided code behaves just as `.index()` does. Also, 1 sorting may be faster than n lookups (needs timing on actual data though).

Answer (score -2):

```
try this one
list(set([1,2,2,3,3,3,4])) will definitely return [1,2,3,4]

as set contains unique elements

Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list(set([1,2,2,3,3,3,4]))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: -1 this absolutely does not preserve order, as `set`s are fundamentally unordered collections. Further, algorithmically speaking, this misses the point that the input is sorted which should allow for making one linear pass over the data (`set` construction is slightly more complicated than that due to the details of hashing).